# Is it possible to separate an object into pieces while maintaining the same faces?

Tags: mesh

I need to be able to separate many reposed versions of a base model into separate body parts. My idea was to manually separate one model into body parts using Blender and then find out which lines in the .obj file correspond to that body part. I could then find these lines in all of my .obj files to separate them into body parts. The problem is that when I export a body part as .obj using blender, the notation for faces does not match the notation for faces in the original model so I cannot find which lines belong to that body part. 
So I am wondering if it is possible to export a body part as .obj while maintaining the same notation for the faces as the original model.